# Magento - override getPrice() not working in Category View

Tags: magento

Trying to multiply all prices by 1.15 in Magento.

```
# /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php

public function getPrice($product)
    {
        return $product->getData('price') * 1.15;
    }
```

This works on the product detail pages for simple and grouped products.

My question : Why does the category page still show the original prices for each product?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is the proper way to do it. Are you trying to just show the prices as 1.15 times the original in the frontend only?

Without fully understanding your intention, to answer your question - I would suggest editing the PHTML files in your themes directory instead. Look for the files `product.phtml` `list.phtml` `configurable.phtml` and `grouped.phtml`.

Actually, a better way to do this might be to override `catalog/product/price.phtml` - this template handles all prices in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's actually related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436950/magento-multiply-price-by-factor-based-on-selected-manufacturer

Comment: That link hopefully explains my intentions :)